naxsi can't block anything
i have an academic project where i have to setup a vlan on which centos and kali are connected to each other. on centos i deployed my flask webapp using nginx, but the problem is when i setup naxsi it doesnt block any type attack. i test xss or command line injection but the naxsi doesnt block the request. Naxsi is supposed to block any type of injection before it gets  to the webapp. everything in my environment is working good. i consulted the logs and everything is working perfectly, but i the naxsi doesn't block anything.
please provide any instruction.
i tried mainrules in naxsi and basicrules, docker containers. i did the job 4 times from scratch but nothing worked.
